# What's the best way to move all open tabs I have open in Safari to Safari Technology Preview instantly?

Tags: mac, safari, macos

Are there any Terminal code or Automator/Applescript I can perform? I have seen a code for Chrome but not for Safari Technology Preview. Any help would be appreciatred.

Comment: Locate the application support folder and preferences plist for both application. Replace the files for one application with that of the other and change application names in the folder/plist as necessary. Then start Safari Technology Preview and restore last session. Theoretically this should work if your replace all Safari or its identifier with Safari Technology Preview or its identifier.

Comment: How many tabs can you have open that you can't just open the one in the other?

Comment: I have 46 tabs.